# Layout with fluid content scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I created this layout for my site

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <p>HEADER</p>
    </div>
    <div id="contentliquid">
        <div id="content">
            <p>CONTENT</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="leftcolumn">
        <p>MENU</p>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>FOOTER</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
body {
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 color:#333
}

p {
 padding: 10px;
}

#wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 min-width: 1000px;
 max-width: 2000px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
 float: left;
 height: 25px;
 width: 100%;
 background: #FF6633;
}

#contentliquid {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
}

#content {
 background: #FFFFFF;
 margin-left: 200px;
}

#leftcolumn {
 float: left;
 background: #CC33FF;
 width: 200px;
 height: 100px;
 margin-left: -100%;
}

#footer {
 height: 40px;
 width: 100%;
 background: #33FF66;
 clear: both;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DL7Xn/)

My goal would be to have a scrollbar only on fluid content (contentliquid) and have leftcolumn height 100%. Is possible to do ? How could I do this ? Thanks

EDIT.

THIS IS MY GOL

[image]

Comment: `html, body{height:100%} div{height:100%;}`  define a fixed height for contentfluid and define `overflow:scroll'

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sT9N7/), hope this will clear the picture for you.

Comment: you can not have 100% of navigation according to your design, Calculate the design, 20 % out of 100% etc... like that other wrong codes/Css are there. rectify them.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things wrong with this.

The header doesn't need to float left for one.  It looks fine.  If anything add a display block.  When using floats, only move items to the left/right that need to be beside another element.

```
#header {
    float: left; // Remove This
    height: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #FF6633;
}
```

Since #leftcolumn floats to the left and is on the left in your design. #contentliquid should float to the right, since this is a left/right column base.  I say this because in your html, #left column came after #contentliquid.  When writing html, anything that you should see first, comes first.  You write the html in order of what is meant to be displayed.

```
<div id="contentliquid">
    <div id="content">
    <p>CONTENT</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="leftcolumn">  // This element should come before #contentliquid
    <p>MENU</p>
</div>
```

You have #contentliquid taking up 100% width, meaning it takes up the entire screen.  This is wrong.  The two elements combined should equal 100% since 120% doesn't exist except for off-screen.  That means #leftcolumn should be 20% and the #contentliquid should be 80%. (or whatever percentages you see fit.

```
#contentliquid {
    float: left;
    width: 100%; //bad : see below
}

<--------------------------------No Room For Anything Else----------------------->
<-----20----><------------------------------80----------------------------------->
```

The #leftcolumn does not need a negative margin-left.  It fits comfortably where it is after adding the fixes i've mentioned.

Finally.  To have a div stay the same height, but scroll with content.  Set the desired height upon it, but set the overflow to auto/scroll.  Either is fine.  It will scroll if the content on the page is more than the room provided for it.

```
#contentliquid {
    float: right;
    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Last but not least, My (updated) JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Az2ws/2/

Comment: your way of writing answer is really appreciable ... truly nice written answer  ..... :)

Comment: sorry but I do not understand, your JSFiddle looks the same as mine.

Comment: @AndrewIce - thank you but unfortunately it is not what I'm looking for. I just want the vertical scrollbar only on contentfluid and leftcolum must be with fixed width.

Comment: No Problem, just make the #leftcontent have a height of 100%, same for contentliquid.  

Leftcontent can have: position: fixed, top: 0, left: 0, width: 20%, height: 100%.

"Main" can have a height of 100%, but most likely with a margin-left of 20% as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could `fixed` the elements and use `percents` and `overflow` properties.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <style>
        html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
        a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
        del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
        small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
        b, u, i, center,
        dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
        fieldset, form, label, legend,
        table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
        article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
        figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
        menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
        time, mark, audio, video {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        font: inherit;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        }
        /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
        article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
        footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
        display: block;
        }
        body {
        line-height: 1;
        }
        ol, ul {
        list-style: none;
        }
        blockquote, q {
        quotes: none;
        }
        blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
        q:before, q:after {
        content: '';
        content: none;
        }
        table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        }
        p {
        padding: 10px;
        }

        #wrapper {
            width: 100%;
            min-width: 1000px;
            max-width: 2000px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            overflow:hidden;
        }

        #header {
            position:fixed;
            z-index:1;
            top:0;
            height: 25px;
            width: 100%;
            background: #FF6633;
        }

        #contentliquid {
            position:absolute;
            top:25px;
            left:20%;
            width: 80%;
            z-index:0;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
        }

        #content {
            background: #FFFFFF;
            overflow:hidden;

        }

        #leftcolumn {
            background: #CC33FF;
            width: 20%;
            height: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            padding-top: 25px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
            z-index: 0;
        }

        #footer {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            height: 40px;
            width: 100%;
            background: #33FF66;
            clear: both;
            z-index:1;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <p>HEADER</p>
        </div>
        <div id="contentliquid">
            <div id="content">
                <p>CONTENT</p>
                <p>CONTENT</p>
                <p>CONTENT</p>
                <p>CONTENT</p>
                <p>CONTENT</p>
                <p>CONTENT</p>
                <p>CONTENT</p>
                <p>CONTENT</p>
                <p>CONTENT</p>
                <p>CONTENT</p>
                <p>CONTENT</p>
                <p>CONTENT</p>
                <p>CONTENT</p>
                <p>CONTENT</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="leftcolumn">
            <p>MENU</p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p>FOOTER</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[You could see this working here](http://jsfiddle.net/NEOLPAR/Dnpg7/1/)

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do. but leftcolumn must be fixed

Comment: You can do this with the leftcolumn fixed size?